# Auto-Disconnect when playing Counter Strike GO

Tags: steam, counter-strike-global-offensive

Is it normal for Steam to randomly go offline if playing CS:GO?

It has happened to me a number of times and sometimes I am automatically disconnected from the match I'm playing.

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

My ping is no bigger than 100 in the scoreboard. Is there a way I can fix this?

Comment: When it does go offline, does your entire PC lose connection too?

Answer (score 2):

If this happened around the time you asked the question, then there were issues with the CS servers last night. I couldn't create a lobby for an hour or so and got disconnected mid-match, but was able to rejoin.

If you have issues, you can check the service status in a number of places:

[Down Detector](https://downdetector.com/status/counter-strike), shows reported issues like so:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

This is usually a good indicator.

You also have the [Steam Service Status page](https://steamstat.us/).